# Java PDF Renderer that uses native codes

Tags: java, pdf, native, pdf-reader

I already know tons of java pdf libraries that have this feature. like `ICEPDF`, `PDFBOX`, `ASPOSE`  `ITEXT`, `JPedal` etc..

and `JMUPDF`, the one that native codes..

I need another one that can provide me this feature (specifically for windows OS)

**Why I need it?**

My Company needs it, we conducted technical investigation on each libraries out there, and I don't want to say every detail here.

pls don't say anything like "it will not be cross-platform", etc..

Any suggestion is appreciated (free, commercial)

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter if the PDF library is using native code or not?

Comment: @immibis yes. there are many advantage in using native codes, though it also have disadvantages.

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all Java PDF libraries?

Comment: Here take a look http://www.dmc.fmph.uniba.sk/public_html/doc/Java/ch20.htm#AdvantagesofUsingNativeMethods haha. Hmmm, not really but I want another library that uses native codes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Fop? http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

It uses xslt transformation to generate the pdf from an XML file

Comment: Thanks, though the output of `FOP` is PDF, the input needed is `XML`. I only need to render `PDF` in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the guys at [Snowbound](http://snowbound.com) software.

Answer (score 0):

You can always compile the code with Exclesior's Jet compiler.